# Looping through <tr> when table ID is passed

Tags: jquery

I have four HTML tables and have to compare data from one table with one that is selected by the user. I am passing the user-selected table ID into this function, but I don't know how to loop through the rows of this table:

```
function callme(code) {

    var tableName = 'table'+code;
    //alert(tableName);

    //How to do loop for this table?? HELP!!
    $('#tableName tr').each(function() {   //how to do
        if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row

        var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
        alert(customerId);
        // call compare function here.
    });
}
```

It should be something very simple for a experienced jQuery programmer. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w7akB/66/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using bad selector, this:

```
$('#tableName tr')
```

means get all `tr` from table with id `tableName`. This is what you want to do:

```
$('#' + tableName +' tr')
```

so you will select table with id stored inside `tableName` variable.

Answer (score 3):

The selector is just a string. You can concatenate the pieces together with your variable:

```
$('#' + tableName + ' tr').each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8zC8/) with this change.